# web.config Rewrite Rules not working in Google App Engine

Tags: asp.net, google-app-engine

I'm deploying an asp.net app to Google App Engine, which is running on the supplied *.appspot.com domain.

I have custom domains setup and working, but would like all requests to the appspot.com address to redirect.  This is my first time using GAE, previously in Azure (which has exactly the same problem) I have added a redirect in the `web.config` file; so I copied my Azure config and re-wrote to the this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect from gcp domain" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".appspot.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://my-domain.com{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But nothing happens, I just remain on the appspot.com domain.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check with these documents: [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing) and [2](https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-redirects-with-rewrite-rules-https-www-and-more/). As per the documents you missed to add negate="true"

Comment: Thanks for your comment; not sure what `negate` should do, but tried it and no difference :(

Comment: Try escaping the pattern in your condition i.e. try ```\.appspot\.com$```

Comment: Nice idea, sadly no change

Comment: Another option - try ```https://my-domain.com/{R:0}``` in your action i.e. there is a trailing slash before your ```{R:N}``` syntax